# Por que as versões 64-bits dos programas tem melhor desempenho, estabilidade e segurança?

Tags: compilação, sistema-operacional, 64-bits

Recentemente, o Google anunciou que a versão Dev do Chrome está disponível também em 64-bits. Provavelmente ela estará disponível também para as versões estáveis no futuro.

O que me chamou atenção, é que o Google disse que a versão 64-bits está **25% mais rápida**, que o **índice de falhas diminuiu pela metade** e que ela também é **mais segura** que a versão 32-bits.

São números bem expressivos! Mas por que o simples fato de compilar em 64-bits traz todos esses benefícios?

---

### Fontes:

- [Tecnoblog - Você já pode testar a versão de 64 bits do Chrome para Windows](http://tecnoblog.net/157786/chrome-canary-64-bits/)
- [The Chromium Blog - Try out the new 64-bit Windows Canary and Dev channels](http://blog.chromium.org/2014/06/try-out-new-64-bit-windows-canary-and.html)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Antes de citar os tópicos que você gostaria de compreender, gostaria de resumir dizendo que os softwares x64 aproveitam o que o SO (sistema operacional) x64 fornece, pois os softwares x32 em SO x64 são emulados, o que acaba por não aproveitar o desempenho máximo que a máquina e o SO são capazes de desempenhar.

**Velocidade**

A respeito disso é a mesma ideia da arquitetura dos processadores que endereçam mais memória.
Software x32 poderá utilizar até 2^32 bits de endereçamento de memória, enquanto que um de x64 armazena até 2^64 bits.
Nos casos que o SO é x64 e o sofware é x32 é feito um processo de emulação para evitar conflitos.

Em citação em um de seus links:

> 64-bit nos permite aproveitar mais o processador e otimizações do compilador, um conjunto de instruções mais moderno, e uma convenção de chamada que permite que mais parâmetros da função serem passados rapidamente para os registros.

Sendo assim, conforme citei, ele aproveita benefícios que só estão disponíveis na arquitetura x64, que são perdidos quando o processador é "obrigado" a não utilizar todo seu endereçamento de memória.

Outro ponto que podemos citar é que o browser por ser x64 torna-se assim totalmente compatível com aplicativos/plugins x64, como o flash player por exemplo. Sendo assim possível justificar a parte em que dizem:

> Como resultado, a velocidade é melhorada, **especialmente em gráficos e conteúdo multimídia**, onde vemos uma melhora média de 25% no desempenho.

**Segurança**

-> Uso de ASLR para maior segurança contra malware

> ASLR é um recurso de segurança que faz com que locais de dados de um programa a ser dispostas aleatoriamente na memória. Antes do ASLR, locais onde os dados de um programa na memória eram armazenados poderia ser previsível, o que tornava ataques a um programa muito mais fácil. Com ASLR, um atacante (hacker) tem de adivinhar o local correto na memória ao tentar explorar uma vulnerabilidade em um programa. Uma suposição incorreta pode resultar em a "queda" do programa, de modo que o atacante não será capaz de tentar novamente.
>
> Esse recurso de segurança também é usado em versões do Windows e outros sistemas operacionais de 32 bits, mas é muito mais poderoso em versões de 64 bits do Windows. Um sistema de 64-bits tem um espaço de endereço muito maior do que um sistema de 32 bits, tornando ASLR muito mais eficaz.

Inclusive em um dos links que postou tem uma parte que fala assim:

> Além disso, o Chrome de 64 bits consegue aproveitar recursos de segurança mais atuais do Windows, como o ASLR (Address Space Load Randomization).

Para melhor esclarecer a respeito da emulação de softwares x32 em OS x64:

Tirado de: http://tecnologiaurbana.com.br/2007/05/diferencas-entre-windows-x32-x64/

> Os processadores AMD64 e IA64T possuem 3 modos de operação diferentes
>
> Modo 32 bits: É possível instalar um sistema operacional de 32 bits nestes sistemas e rodar programas 32 bits, entretanto, eles não serão capazes de fazer uso das novas funcionalidades exclusivas de 64 bits como endereçamento real de memória acima de 4GB ou dos registradores GPRs.
>
> Modo de compatibilidade: É um modo intermediário do modo completo (full). Para rodar no modo de compatibilidade, é necessário instalar um sistema operacional de 64 bits com drivers de 64 bits. O modo de compatibilidade com um sistema operacional de 64 bits possibilita rodar programas de 32 bits sem modificações. Cada programa 32 bits deve estar limitado à no máximo 4 GB de memória física. Porém, este limite de 4 GB é imposto em um nível de pré-processo e não em um nível de sistema. Isso significa que cada processo de 32 bits neste sistema pode ter seu próprio bloco de memória de 4 GB de espaço de memória física (supondo que se tenha bastante memória física instalada).
>
> Modo completo (full) de 64 bits: Este modo é ativado quando são executados programas de 64 bits em sistemas operacionais de 64 bits. Neste modo, um programa pode ter um espaço de endereçamento virtual de até 40 bits (cerca de 1 TB de memória endereçável).
>   Programas que rodam no modo completo terão acesso à toda memória física instalada e às GPRs expandidas do sistema. Mas é importante entender que este modo de operação só estará ativo em um sistema operacional de 64 bits com drivers de 64 bits rodando programas de 64 bits.

**Estabilidade**

Essa questão é um pouco mais complicada, mas pelo que pude entender no caso do chrome, eles tinham bastante crash durante processos de renderização.
Como deve saber processo de renderização usa bastante capacidade computacional, inclusive se pesquisar irá ver diversas reclamações a respeito de pessoas reclamando que o chrome usava 100% de CPU para renderizar e depois travava, isso acaba diminuindo se o chrome tem em suas mãos a chance de usar mais memória acredito eu.

Conforme citei, podemos verificar esta questão acompanhando o que a Intel disse a respeito dos benefícios do uso do x64:

> Mais Acesso à Memória Física
>
> As aplicações nativas x64, combinadas com as edições x64 do Windows Server e com o hardware adequado, podem acessar até 2 terabytes (TB) da RAM física, permitindo a execução de aplicações de servidor de alto consumo de memória.
>
> Elimine as Limitações de Endereços Virtuais
>
> Nos sistemas de 32 bits, as aplicações orientadas a conexão requerem o kernel de sistema operacional para utilizar uma parte do seu espaço de memória de 2 gigabytes. Quando as aplicações, tais como os servidores de terminal, escalonam para suportar mais usuários, este limite de alocação de memória pode se tornar um obstáculo independentemente da capacidade da RAM física do sistema. As edições x64 do Windows Server fornecem um espaço de endereço virtual de 8 TB para o kernel e para cada processo do sistema.
>
> Desempenho Melhorado
>
> Enquanto as aplicações de 32 bits têm um desempenho semelhante nas edições de 32 bits do Windows Server e nas edições x64 do Windows Server, as aplicações x64 nativas podem apresentar significantes melhoras de desempenho, particularmente para as aplicações com alta demanda de processamento.

------- Edit ----------

**WOW64**

> WoW64 (Windows 32-bit on Windows 64-bit) é um subsistema do sistema operacional Windows capaz de executar aplicações de 32-bit e está incluída em todas as versões 64-bit do Windows.

Este emulador possui algumas dlls para que isso ocorra:

> - Wow64.dll fornece a infra-estrutura de emulação de núcleo e os
>     subsuperfície, para as funções de ponto de entrada Ntoskrnl.exe.
> - Wow64win.dll fornece "thunks" para as funções de ponto de entrada Win32k.sys.
> - Wow64Cpu.dll é uma biblioteca de interface que abstrai características do processador hospedeiro.
> - (Intel Itanium apenas) IA32Exec.bin contém o software emulador x86.
> - (Intel Itanium apenas) Wowia32x.dll fornece a interface entre IA32Exec.bin e WOW64.

Conforme tópico oficial da microsoft, podemos ver que a própria empresa afirma que executar um software x32 em SO x64 não é um processo perfeito:
Link: [http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/windows/desktop/aa384219(v=vs.85).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/windows/desktop/aa384219%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

> Emulação de Instrução é realizada no chip. No processador x64, instruções são executadas nativamente pelo micro-arquitetura. Portanto, a velocidade de execução no WOW64 em x64 é **semelhante** à sua velocidade em 32 bits do Windows. No processador Intel Itanium, mais software está envolvido na emulação e o **desempenho sofre como resultado.**

Na página da Wikipédia US a respeito, é citado mais um detalhe importante:
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WoW64

> According to Microsoft, 32-bit software running under WOW64 has a similar performance when executing under 32-bit Windows, but with **fewer threads possible and other overheads.**

Conforme é de se imaginar (mesmo que não seja bom), dlls nativas x32 são diferentes das dlls WOW64:

http://www.nynaeve.net/?p=131

> Se olharmos para o ntdll x86 nativo, vemos a chamada esperada pelos ponteiros SystemCallStub em SharedUserData:
>
> 0:000> u ntdll! NtClose
>
> ntdll ZwClose:
>
> mov eax, 30h
>
> mov edx, offset SharedUserData! SystemCallStub
>
> call dword ptr [edx]
>
> ret 4
>
> No entanto, um exame da Wow64 mostra ntdll algo diferente; uma chamada é feita através de um campo no deslocamento + C0 no TEB 32 bits:
>
> 0:000> u ntdll! NtClose
>
> ntdll ZwClose:
>
> eax mov, 0Ch
>
> xor ecx, ecx
>
> lea edx, [esp +4]
>
> call PTR DWORD fs: [0C0h]
>
> ret 4

Ainda acho necessário comentar sobre um bug no WOW64 (**Até o momento não corrigido no Windows 7** segundo informações de blogs que explicam o assunto):

Bug: http://zachsaw.blogspot.com.br/2010/11/wow64-bug-getthreadcontext-may-return.html

Refere-se a: *Coletor de Lixo Boehm (Boehm GC)*

Answer (score 12):

## Segurança

Com um sistema de 64 bits é possível utilizar [ASLR](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Address_space_layout_randomization) que a grosso modo protege contra ataques de stack overflow (ou buffer overflow). Assim impedindo que o cracker pule de um  exploid para uma função direta (IAT Hook ou outros tipos de hook como o Detours também podem ser evitados com isso). Facilita o uso do polimorfismo que é muito usado por malwares mas também pode ser utilizado por programas comuns para não terem uma "assinatura" constante em suas funções, e isso é muito útil, já que a maiorias dos hooks utilizam um scan de memoria para encontrar padrões, assim encontrando o endereço de uma função por exemplo.

## Velocidade

Programas que rodam a 64 bits tem um acesso mais rápido ao registro  (por ser um registro diferente do 32 bits).[Mais informações](http://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/windows/desktop/ms724072%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

Além das vantagens listadas acima, até hoje debugges (como OllyODBG e IDA) tem dificuldade na leitura de sistemas 64 bits, não é isso que vai deixar o sistema mais seguro, mas isso já impede que 80% dos crackers "comuns" façam alguma coisa.

[Simples classe de polimorph](http://pastebin.com/U1LWWJJR)
[Polychaos](https://github.com/DarthTon/Polychaos)

Comment: ASLR é usado em 32-bit sem problema algum. Não entendi o que quis dizer com polimorfismo no contexto  Pode explicar?

Comment: Desculpe, ASLR que só é possível no 64 bits é o [High Entropy](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh156527.aspx). Sobre o polimorfismo, ele pode trazer a segurança de não manter o mesmo pattern para cada função a cada execução, dificultando os famosos "find pattens" a terem um resultado satisfatório

Comment: Adicionei uma recompensa de +100 na pergunta porque acredito que ela merece uma resposta mais completa. Talvez você se interesse em aprofundar mais a sua resposta, dando mais detalhes, etc.

Answer (score 4):

A resposta está no próprio link da pergunta: [The Chromiun Blog - Try out the new 64-bit Windows Canary and Dev channels](http://blog.chromium.org/2014/06/try-out-new-64-bit-windows-canary-and.html).

O aumento de velocidade não é só porque é 64 bits, mas porque a arquitetura dos processadores x86-64 teve várias outras mudanças que melhoraram o desempenho (ou seja, não só registradores maiores, como também mais registradores e novas instruções).

> 64-bit nos permite aproveitar mais o processador e otimizações do compilador, um conjunto de instruções mais moderno, e uma convenção de chamada que permite que mais parâmetros da função serem passados rapidamente em registradores.

A convenção de chamadas é como o programa organiza os parâmetros para uma chamada de função. Isso é específico da combinação processador + sistema operacional, e por ter mais registradores um x86-64 tem a possibilidade de passar mais parâmetros em registradores em vez de colocar na pilha, que tende a ser mais lenta.

> especialmente em gráficos e conteúdo multimídia

Gráficos e multimídia aplicam muito uma operação repetida a vários números (para transformar pixels, por exemplo), e há muito tempo os processadores vêm ganhando mais instruções que ajudam a fazer isso, desde o tempo do MMX, depois SSE, SSE2, e os processadores 64 bits têm ainda mais registradores SSE que os de 32 bits.

E sobre segurança, já foi bem explicado ali no post do Giovani, com mais bits para os ponteiros, é possível alocar memória de maneira pouco previsível, evitando que código maligno possa prever onde na memória foi inserida alguma estrutura de dados importante.